# Why is Xamarin.Android not building on custom agent, but builds with VSTS default visual studio 2017 agent and in visual studio?

Tags: java, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, azure-devops

### The problem

I am working on setting up a CI pipeline in Azure Dev Ops and using a custom agent as a build server, however, I cannot get it to build.  If I run the project in visual studio 2017 **on the build server** it will build.  But if I run the custom agent to build the project on the **VSTS ci pipeline, it does not build** with the following errors:

```
Resources\values\styles.xml(2): error APT0000: Error retrieving parent for 
  item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
```

If I run the ci pipeline using the **"Host VS2017" agent**, it builds fine.

### This is what I have done so far:

1. Updated Android SDK
2. Restarted computer
3. Updated Visual Studio 2017

### Versions of Host VS2017 Agent:

Java SDK version 1.8.0

Android Platform API level: 27

TargetFrameworkVersion: v8.1
Android NDK: \

Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\

Android SDK Build Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\

Java SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.9\

Xamarin.Android 9.1.7.0

### Versions of My Machine (Build Server/Custom Agent)

Java SDK version 1.8.0

Android Platform API level: 27

TargetFrameworkVersion: v8.1

Android NDK: C:\Microsoft\AndroidNDK64\android-ndk-r13b\

Android SDK: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\

Android SDK Build Tools: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\

Java SDK: C:\Program Files\Android\jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\

Xamarin.Android 9.1.7.0

### Initial thoughts:

My first thoughts are that it's a problem with the SDK versioning, but I'm not sure.
My other thought is maybe it's a problem with nuget getting the AppCompat package correctly.  I'm not sure how to continue from here in figuring out what the issue is.

### Resources I have looked at for context:

Someone else had this issue with the SDK
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59017/no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-theme-appcompat-light

Someone had a similar issue to mine, but a solution was not found
[Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46280933/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-attr)

Had a problem due to how the nuget packages were being restored for Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat
https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Android.FSharp.ResourceProvider/issues/3

Comment: Have you thought about switching to AppCenter? Much easier to get working.

Comment: @BradDixon I have looked at AppCenter and it definitely looks much easier to get running.  The problem, however, is that I need the CI pipeline to be faster.  At the moment it takes 15 minutes to build, making integration of pull requests into the main branch rather slow.  I am also having problems getting AppCenter to build, but probably is just something simple.  I am getting "error MSB4018: The "ReadLibraryProjectImportsCache" task failed unexpectedly."

Comment: not sure about the error but if you have other projects you’re referencing then you will need a pre build script to pull those references in. The little help chat in the bottom right hand corner is gold, those guys are seriously good so use it if you get stuck. Sorry I couldn’t help further.